# Call async function after X seconds as part of Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a function, where I iterate an array and create an array of promises. Then execute all promises as part of `Promise.all`.

But the functions need to be called only after a timeout passes.

```
async function main()

{

   const promisesArray: Promise<void>[] = [];

   for (const userRecord of records) {

      promisesArray.push(verifyUserRecord(userRecord.userId));

   }

    setTimeout(async function () {
        await Promise.all(promisesArray);
    }, 60 * 1000);
}
```

**Async function**

```
 async function verifyUserRecord(userId) {
    ///////// 
}
```

Please advise if my implementation idea is correct.

Comment: What does "correct" mean here? Why do you want to wait a minute before calling `Promise.all()` on the returned promises?

Comment: I want to execute `verifyUserRecord` after a minute passes.

Comment: Then that's not correct. The calls to `verifyUserRecord()` (assuming it really is asynchronous) will finish when they finish.

Comment: The calls to verifyUserRecord are made immediately.  The current code waits a minute before checking if all those promises completed.  Not sure what the intention is

Comment: @James the goal is to call `verifyUserRecord` after a minute

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev You need to make the call to `verifyUserRecord` dependent on the completion of the timeout. Currently you invoke the `verify...` function at the time of adding it to the array.

Comment: @404 you are correct, my mistake

Comment: Yep. you need to return your promise in `verifyUserRecord` instead of awaiting it in place. let `Promise.all` await them.